# Is there any truth behind violent & risky (suicidal) behavior occurring with lunar cycles, i.e. full moons? Why (if actually true)?

Tags: medical-myths, violent-behavior, suicide, emergency-room

Rumors have been perpetuated that emergency rooms and jail cells are full during full moons due to increase in risky and violent behaviors. Is this just an urban legend or is there any merit of truth behind it.

1. If there is some form of legitimacy to it, what is the medical (or geophysical)
   reason behind it?
2. And if it's not true, why did human behavior become associated with
   the moon?
3. Does the moon impact human behavior in any way? (Heard of menstrual cycles...)

Comment: Do you have valid sources for this rumours? Then this question might be a better fit ion Skeptics.SE

Comment: already asked about crime there:http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/948/31357 (Spoiler: no increase in crime due to moon phase.) They have a moon tag, with 34 questions.